# How to keep a constant value of a variable during the execution of the code in Matlab

Tags: matlab, variables, constants, cycle, execution

I have a short (and I reckon silly as well) question about manipulation of variables in Matlab codes. How can I keep a constant value of a variable (assigned during the execution of the code), while the code executes further? So basically put the value into the memory and don't change it all. As an example of the code on which I am working right now:

```
 if SystemTriggered ==1;     
   if Accelerationflag == 1;
     for n = 1:1:100
         AOrder = 1/2*HMSpeed^2/(Acc+n*2*pi);
            if AOrder<Alim;
                k = n;
                Accelerationflag = 0;
                break;
            end
        end
    end
    Offset = k;
    AccOffset = PhaseIni - Offset*2*pi;
    %Derivation conditions
    if My condition here;
        HmSpeedReached = 1;
    end
  end
```

So I am looking for an option, how I can keep the calculated value of "Offset" when I got "HmSpeedReached =1". Since we have a "for" cycle in the beginning (that will assign a value to K and then to Offset), so I just need to keep that number as a value of the variable all the time, after the condition of HmSpeedReached is satisfied... 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you considered using a vector where you assign the value to the element matching the current iteration? Or you could append the values to a log file if you want to be sure they persist after the program terminates.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Well, I can use a log file. But I can easily get the required "Offset" value by using some of the Simulink blocks as well. But in my case, I am looking for an option how to keep the value of "Offset" while the is executing. Due to the nature of the Simulink model (the code is part of it), the cycle "for" can be executed again, so it will overwrite the value of "Offset" after we get HmSpeedReached = 1. Sorry that I did not specify the presence of the Simulink model in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly then you want the following:

- Keep assigning `Offset = k` whilst looping through your code
- If `HmSpeedReached = 1` has been set, then don't change the `Offset` value

This code (adapted from yours) should work

```
% Initially make sure HmSpeedReached is not equal to 1
HmSpeedReached = 0;
% Your code with addition...
if SystemTriggered ==1;     
   if Accelerationflag == 1;
       for n = 1:1:100
           AOrder = 1/2*HMSpeed^2/(Acc+n*2*pi);
           if AOrder<Alim;
               k = n;
               Accelerationflag = 0;
               break;
           end
       end
    end
    % Add a condition here to check if Offset should be updated, if HmSpeedReached is not 1
    if HmSpeedReached ~= 1
        Offset = k;
    end 

    AccOffset = PhaseIni - Offset*2*pi;
    %Derivation conditions
    if My condition here;
      HmSpeedReached = 1;
    end
end
```

If instead you want to save a vector of `Offset` values, every time some condition is met, then use something like this:

```
Offset = [];
HmSpeedReached = 0;
if SystemTriggered ==1;     
    if Accelerationflag == 1;
        for n = 1:1:100
            AOrder = 1/2*HMSpeed^2/(Acc+n*2*pi);
            if AOrder<Alim;
                k = n;
                Accelerationflag = 0;
                break;
            end
        end
    end
    % Add a condition here to check if Offset should be updated, if HmSpeedReached is not 1
    if CONDITION FOR SAVING OFFSET
        Offset = [Offset, k];
    end 

    AccOffset = PhaseIni - Offset*2*pi;
    %Derivation conditions
    if My condition here;
        HmSpeedReached = 1;
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much! As I was thinking, it will be a simple solution. I've checked the first modified code and it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Assign HmSpeedReached = 0 at the top and test for HmSpeedReached equal zero as a condition to change the variable Offset.